# How to write accented characters from XML into MarkLogic using JavaApi?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, marklogic, iso-8859-1

I have an **XML** of 20MB having accented characters like Ö,É,Á, and many more.Here the problem is when i insert file into MarkLogic, these characters are saved in English format like O,E,A.but i want to store in same format.So how can i store the characters in accented format and read the **XMl** in same way. My XML file is **ISO-8859-1** encoded.

Code which i have written for writing and reading  :

```
     DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, PORT,
        DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = null;
    streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("record.xml"));
    XMLDocumentManager xmlDocMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
    XMLStreamReaderHandle handle = new XMLStreamReaderHandle(streamReader);
    xmlDocMgr.write("/" + filename, handle);
```

For reading XML:

```
 XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
 DOMHandle xmlhandle = new DOMHandle();
docMgr.read("/" + filename, xmlhandle);
String doc = xmlhandle.toString();
String data = Normalizer.normalize(doc, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
return data;
```

I Am returning Data to display in browser.
Not able to find where the problem is.

Comment: Why not save in UTF-8?

Comment: @JoopEggen , There are many XMl files like this encoded in ISO.So I cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML file does not have an XML prologue that declares its encoding, you should specify the ISO-8859-1 encoding when reading the file before writing the file to the database (as flafoux has pointed out).

You should also specify the encoding when reading the content from the database unless the destination accepts UTF-8 encoding.

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_11208

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the encoding (and also change constructor using `InputStream`) :

```
XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("record.xml"),"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: i specified encoding, but still it is saving in English format.